# How to pass arguments to an already running python program?

Tags: python, django, load

I'm using a Django framwork, and have to pass new query to a python script. However, that python program have to read a large data file, and it takes 2 minutes to load the data. So I want to load the data only once, and just pass new query to the running python program, then it will be fast enough for web users. Unfortunately, I have searched a lot, but still don't know how to implement it.

Comment: I'm not sure if they'll work, but try out using `subprocess.Popen` with the `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` parameter. [Read about `Popen` on the docs.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects)

Comment: Sounds like you want a database

Answer (score -1):

One method is to read a communication file:

```
oldid = -1

while True:
    f = open("communication","r")
    t = f.read()
    f.close()
    t = t.split("==")
    id = int(t[0])
    query = t[1]
    if id > oldid:
        # the query was not handled yet
        stuff to handle your query ...
        oldid = id
```

You write a file which looks so: ID==QUERY
Replace id and query with your wishes. Count id +1 if you push a new query. You could use a script for that.